# How to scan binary file for string pattern in Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am writing customization for an old application, and so I don't have modern programming languages available to me.  However, I can call WinAPI functions.  I need to seek a specific string in a binary file (could be anywhere), but I can't find a WinAPI function that will do that.  I want to search for '< Release >' in the file, and then scan the next characters after that up to '< /Release >'.  Hopefully someone remembers that ancient tech, how to do that?

Comment: no need for win api. VB6 can handle binary files. in fact here is an article I found looking for HTML tags in VB6. Good luck. http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/reading-and-writing-binary-files-visual-basic

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Really...almost a year later?!? :)